# Null numpy array to be appended to

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing a feature selection code. Basically get the output from featureselection function and concatenate it to the numpy array data

```
data=np.zeros([1,4114]) # put feature length here
for i in range(1,N):
    filename=splitpath+str(i)+'.tiff'
    feature=featureselection(filename)
    data=np.vstack((data, feature))

data=data[1:,:] # remove the first zeros row
```

However, this is not a robust implementation as I need to know feature length (4114) beforehand.

Is there any null numpy array matrix, like in Python list we have []?

Answer (score 3):

Appending to a numpy array in a loop is inefficient, there might be some situations when it cannot be avoided but this doesn't seem to be one of them. If you know the size of the array that you'll end up with, it's best to just per-allocate the array, something like this:

```
data = np.zeros([N, 4114])
for i in range(1, N):
    filename = splitpath+str(i)+'.tiff'
    feature = featureselection(filename)
    data[i] = feature
```

Sometimes you don't know the size of the final array. There are several ways to deal with this case, but the simplest is probably to use a temporary list, something like:

```
data = []
for i in range(1,N):
    filename = splitpath+str(i)+'.tiff'
    feature = featureselection(filename)
    data.append(feature)

data = np.array(data)
```

Just for completeness, you can also do `data = np.zeros([0, 4114])`, but I would recommend against that and suggest one of the methods above.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to assume the size before creating the first array, you can use lazy initialization.

```
data = None
for i in range(1,N):
    filename=splitpath+str(i)+'.tiff'
    feature=featureselection(filename)
    if data is None:
        data = np.zeros(( 0, feature.size ))
    data = np.vstack((data, feature))

if data is None:
    print 'no features'
else:
    print data.shape
```